# PHPUnit and mocking dependencies

Tags: php, mocking, phpunit

I'm writing a test for the Service class. As you can see below, my Service class uses the Gateway class. I'd like to mock the output of `getSomething()` on the Gateway class in one of my tests.

I tried with stubs (`createStub`) & mocks (`getMockBuilder`), but PHPUnit does not produce the desired result.

*My classes:*

```
<?php

class GatewayClass
{
    private $client = null;

    public function __construct(Client $client)
    {
        $this->client = $client->getClient();
    }

    public function getSomething()
    {
        return 'something';
    }
}
```

```
<?php

class Service
{
    private $gateway;

    public function __construct(Client $client)
    {
        $this->gateway = new Gateway($client);
    }

    public function getWorkspace()
    {
        return $this->gateway->getSomething();
    }
}
```

(this project does not have a DI container yet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To mock your `Gateway` class, you have to inject it into the `Service`.

```
class Service
{
    private $gateway;

    public function __construct(Gateway $gateway)
    {
        $this->gateway = $gateway;
    }

    public function getWorkspace()
    {
        return $this->gateway->getSomething();
    }
}
```

```
class ServiceTest
{
    public function test()
    {
        $gateway = $this->createMock(Gateway::class);
        $gateway->method('getSomething')->willReturn('something else');
        $service = new Service($gateway);

        $result = $service->getWorkspace();

        self::assertEquals('something else', $result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, any difference between `createMock` and `createStub`? I was trying with a stub myself, but do see that you are using a mock.

Comment: Stub is actually the correct term. The `createStub` method is rather new and I haven't adopted it fully yet. Technically, you'll get the same kind of object from both methods (at least in the current version of PHPUnit), but it's good to differentiate the various types of test doubles. Here's a brief overview: https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TestDouble.html